# How to embed react inside HTML that has been dangerously set?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing an app that wraps a react shell around documents, PDFs, and text files that have been converted into HTML strings, and also sanitized webpage HTML.  The shell dynamically manages global styling (styles components) and communicates with a React Native app via react-native-webview to execute various operations on the HTML.To swap out the current page viewed by the user, I use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML property on a container component.

I have read that it's fine to call the render method in a root created by react.createRoot multiple times across a regular webpage. First question I have is whether this should only be done at a sibling level, or can I replace parts of HTML that have been dangerously set inside a react component? In other words, is it ok to make nested calls to root.render?

I would also like to know whether it is possible to nest components inside dangerously set HTML but have them tied into the render cycle of the React tree that manages my app container?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, and spending a lot of time writing a lot of code I am not proud of, the answer to question 1 is don't.  Don't nest roots, react errors out when it tries to reference parts of the DOM that other react trees have changed.  It's basically punching holes in the parent DOM.

As for question 2, if the goal is to manipulate document content without compromising the virtual DOM, and also being able to insert custom components into injected document content (like HTML blog articles, word docs converted to HTML, markdown files converted to html) that are tied into react, then the unified.js ecosystem, and in particular the hast/rehype/rehype-react libraries in that ecosystem are the way to go.

My use case was highlighting text in documents.  Rehype lets you make all those find and replace operations virtually by changing an abstract syntax tree representing an HTML document. You can pass the result into rehype-react where it is converted to react and then pass the react result as a child component.  Multiple find and replace operations but one render cycle (may have that wrong).

Maybe I missed the memo. But it seems to me searching and changing the dom of variable subject matter isn't something react can do alone, but it works well with an AST.

Not a great answer, but I can clarify if anybody sees this.and wants to know more.